# что не так с syntax mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

в sh скрипте есть такой код

```
export wp_and_db_user="${VESTACP_USER}_${HOST_PREFIX}"
export wp_and_db_pass=${VESTACP_PASS}

mysql -u${wp_and_db_user} -p${wp_and_db_pass} << EOF
use ${wp_and_db_user}

UPDATE `wp_users` SET
`ID` = '1',
`user_login` = '${wp_and_db_user}',
`user_pass` = md5('${wp_and_db_pass}'),
`user_nicename` = '${wp_and_db_user}',
`user_email` = 'timemail@test.com',
`user_url` = '',
`user_registered` = '2019-05-19 11:28:16',
`user_activation_key` = '',
`user_status` = '0',
`display_name` = '${wp_and_db_user}'
WHERE `ID` = '1';

EOF
```

а вот сама ошибка

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET = '1', = 'admin_resour', = md5('ODUyNzJmYmEyMmZhMzNmMj'), = 'admin_resour', ' at line 1
```

хотя эти команды я проверял в phpmyadmin и они работают, почему я получаю ошибку

Comment: Всё, что между апострофами ` интерпретируется как команды, которые нужно выполнить. Баш пытается запускать команды `wp_users`, `ID`, `user_login` и так далее, эти команды оказываются не найдены, и поэтому в результате подставляется пустота.

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать все апострофы обратным слэшем, вот так: \\` или вообще убрать их, они здесь не очень нужны

Comment: да апострофы убрал сработало

Comment: Не бэктики нужно убирать, а использовать другой синтаксис heredoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, вы используете HEREDOC с интерполяцией, он ведёт себя подобно строке в двойных кавычках, в частности воспринимает строки в бэктиках(``` `` ```) как команды, результат выполнения которых попадает в итоговую строку:

```
$ cat << EOF
Date: `date` 
EOF 
Date: Чт июн 27 20:52:13 +07 2019
```

Существует другой синтаксис HEREDOC, без интерполяции:

```
$ cat << 'EOF'
String: `date`
EOF
String: `date`
```

Обратите внимание на апострофы вокруг EOF.